# Creating an Ethereum id Hash

Tags: web3.py, hash

I'm trying to understand how to convert my transaction data into the id hash **before signing the transaction**.

Let's say I have this data:

```
transaction = {
    'to': to_address,
    'from': from_address,
    'value': 4200000000000000,
    'gas': 21000,
    'gasPrice': 22000000000,
    'chainId': 1,
    'nonce': '0x0'
}
```

How can I convert this into the id hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the transaction hash that most web3 APIs use, like `w3.eth.getTransaction(transaction_hash)`?

That transaction hash is generated from the signed and rlp-encoded transaction. There isn't a way to predict the final transaction hash without signing it.

Comment: Thanks @carver. That's what I suspected. I'm using BlockCypher today and it looks they do provide this hash. I'll double-check it now.